# Use <div> as a button and trigger a mailto when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I'm creating a custom button on my webpage which actually is a `<div>`, I want to trigger a mailto when the button is clicked. What is the best way out?

I've tried calling a javascript function using-onClick that looks like this -

```
function foo(){
    window.open("mailto:xyz@abc.com");
}
```

But that opens a new tab in Chrome first, and then asks for the relevant app to send out the email. This experience is different from what we generally get when we simply do a `<a href=mailto:.....>` in HTML.

I can also create a new document element in the JS function, and simulate a click like this -

```
function sendEmail() {
    var mail = 'mailto:contact@test.com';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = mail;
    a.click();
};
```

But i'm not too sure if that's the right way! Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: Is there any reason for using a `<div>` and not a block `<a>`? Are you able to change the markup/CSS?

Comment: I'm not able to fully customize the button if I use the <a> tag, that's why I resorted to <div>

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean customize? You can style a `<a>` just like you can style a `<div>`, providing you display it as a block

Comment: Do you have a link or a fiddle that I could refer to? My button has an image too, and yes, the page consists of multiple floating elements so I cannot use the block display.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if *you* could post your markup, then we could see what your doing wrong

Comment: Listen to @Aurovrata. His answer is more professional. Otherwise I'll really have problems with spam.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use an anchor tag but change the display property to block:

**HTML**

```
<a class="mailto" href="mailto:contact@test.com">Mail</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.mailto{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 66):

Try this, and tell me if works. (If not, I will delete answer.)

```
<script>
function sendEmail() 
{
    window.location = "mailto:xyz@yourapplicationdomain.com";
}
</script>
<div onclick="sendEmail();">Send e-mail</div>
```

It is possible to pass the parameters **subject** and **body**, but I think that it is not possible to format the text:

```
<a href='mailto:xyz@yourapplicationdomain.com?subject=Me&body=Hello!'>EMAIL</a>
```

Comment: Good answer.  I prefer window.open(mailto:xyz@abc.com) though...as this will not take the user away from your app, but will still launch the email client.

Comment: Did you test this, @skidadon? It doesn't take you away from the app/site. It just launches the client

Comment: Does not take user away from site, on Chrome and Safari at least.

Comment: Getting taken away from the site, and whether or not a external client is opened instead, is based on how the user's email client is configured. If the user doesn't have an external email client configured, then you will be directed away from the site.

Comment: how to pass formatted email body message.. Like i want to use <bold> tag.

Comment: It is possible to pass the parameters subject and body, but I think that it is not possible to format the text: <a href='mailto:me@me.com?subject=Me&body=Hello!'>EMAIL</a>

Comment: Can confirm. If the e-mail client is a tab in your browser, it will redirect away from your app onto the e-mail website. Therefore, it's only safe to avoid it with `window.open`, as was previously pointed out correctly.

Answer (score 32):

Extremely late to the party I know, but what about combining these answers into something simpler and more practical:

```
<div class="button" onclick="location.href='mailto:xyz@abc.com';">Send E-Mail</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
function sendEmail() 
{
    window.location.assign("mailto:xyz@abc.com");
}
</script>
<div onclick="sendEmail();">Send e-mail</div>
```

@Tony has used the same approach just `assign` has been added.

Answer (score 7):

In order to obfuscate your email from SPAM bots that scan website for emails, you can do the following,

```
<div class="button" onclick="location.href='mail'+'to:xyz'+'@'+abc'+'.'+'com';">Send E-Mail</div>
```

and instead of the 'Send E-Mail' text you can place an image of your actual email address (screenshot) to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 6):

Try this function and html. It will open a new email client with.

```
<div onclick="doMail();">


function doMail() {

    var email ="xyz@abc.com";
    location.href = "mailto:"+email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="mailtoperformingFunction('inner');" id="divbutton">

<script type="text/javascript">
function mailtoperformingFunction()
{
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="button" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="location.href='mailto:abc@xyz.com';">Click to Send email</div>
```

Comment: Hi, why do you think this will work? :) Edit your post and explain please